# MATLAB Gradient Error - Error in gradient

Tags: gradient

Pretty basic, just trying an example from my Calc 3 class, and the gradient function refuses to work:

```
f = @(x) x*(1)^2 + x*(2)^2 + x(1)*x(2)*x(3);
a = [-2,1,-3];
h = 0.1;
df = gradient(f,a,h)
```

Command Window:
Unary operator '.'' is not supported for operand of type 'function_handle'.

Error in gradient>parse_inputs (line 139)
f = f.';

Error in gradient (line 48)
[f,ndim,loc,rflag] = parse_inputs(f,varargin);

Error in lab4Examples (line 12)
df = gradient(f,a,h)

tried both on MATLAB online as well as the WIN11 app, same result

Any help would be appreciated